# CAS Authentication using Annotations

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas, jhipster

I have project based on JHipster and I have to implement CAS authentication to have SSO to 2 applications (one is this java jHipster project and another is php app). I found sample configuration in [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html), but it uses xml configuration. Is there any existing implementation/tutorial using java configuration for CAS client? I'm totally new on this topic, so every hint will be useful.

Comment: I found this: http://www.objectpartners.com/2014/05/20/configuring-spring-security-cas-providers-with-java-config/ . I'll try to use this solution in jHipster.

Answer (score 2):

I've just made a project example with jhipster and CAS auth : https://github.com/jgribonvald/demo-spring-cas-angular.git

feedback is welcome ;)